# how do i get mod_rewrite to execute the RewriteRules if and only if there is no parameter q= in the url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

the below code works to deal with my url structures but i need the rules not to work if there is parameter q= in the url.

i tried to set up a rewritecond (in the commented out line below) without success,

please help! thanks :)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q!=(.*)
RewriteRule ^FSD/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?service=$1&type=FSD [NC]
RewriteRule ^ECD/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?service=$1&type=ECD [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ /index.php?category=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond`'s test pattern is a little off, but you got the right idea:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(\A|&)q=.*
```

Note that the `RewriteCond` only applies to the next `RewriteRule`, so if you want to perform this exclusion for all four of your rules, you'll need to copy the `RewriteCond` above each of them.